# jquery validation position error label

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

[image: http://s4.postimage.org/bpmlh7b65/error.jpg]

and this also not worked for me an error occurd when I tried this:

```
error.insertBefore(element)
error.css('float','left')
```

or:

```
error.attr('style','float:left')
```

only I can add these properties like this:

```
$(error).someproperty
```

This is my code as I can't copy paste because I work on TFS and copy/paste is not allowed.  Problem is that with this code I can not `float left` error message. I want that error should appear on left and below the textbox.  One thing more, I was just testing and I put `float =right` in picture above so forget about it. `float:left` is also not working.  I have checked it.

Comment: Please put the actual code in the OP, not a picture of the code.  Also, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Just because you can't copy and paste doesn't mean you can't just type it out... It's still not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules), `rules('add', rules)` is only a method for adding your **`rules`** and their messages, nothing else.  You've *improperly* placed `errorElement:`, `wrapper:`, and `errorPlacement:` within your `rules('add', rules)` method.

`errorElement:`, `wrapper:`, and `errorPlacement:` are **not** `rules`.  These are called **options** and therefore would only be placed within [`.validate(options)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        wrapper: 'div',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element); // default function
        }
    });
});
```

Otherwise, I don't know what you're asking and you should put your actual code within the OP, so we don't have to re-type it in order to answer.

Comment: ok sorry to all of you , it was not my intention to disturb you all and clearly its my fault that i was in a hurry and i cant explain and write my question well next time i will be careful and special thanx to you Sparky .. i have understood what i was doing wrong ,thank you ryley for your reply i have solved my problem now May God bless you all:) Thanks again