# jquery validation text alignment

Tags: jquery, css, validation

using [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org)

see: http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3v5/205/

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div>
    <form id="everything">
        <label for="dd1">Select the best option</label>
        <br/>
        <select name="dd1" id="dd1" class="required">
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="o1">option 1</option>
            <option value="o2">option 2</option>
            <option value="o3">option 3</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input id="agreement" name="agreement" type="checkbox"><b> I accept the TOS</b>
            <br/>
        <input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

I have multiple fields which display the error messages on their right. My problem is, the validation message for checkbox appears between the checkbox and its label.

> [checkbox]
>
> ```
>           [validation message] [label]
> ```

But I want it this way:

> **[checkbox]  - [label]**
>
> [validation message]

How can I acheive this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625228/jquery-validation-position-error-label

Comment: BIOS.  This looks like what I'm looking at but do you know where I can find a complete example (jsfiddle would be best)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I was looking for 
http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3v5/223/

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div>
    <form id="everything">
        <label for="dd1">Select the best option</label>
        <br/>
        <select name="dd1" id="dd1" class="required">
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="o1">option 1</option>
            <option value="o2">option 2</option>
            <option value="o3">option 3</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <label for='agreement'>I accept the TOS</label>
        <input id="agreement" name="agreement" type="checkbox" style='float:left' />
        <br/>
        <div id="everything2"></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3v5/208/)  add float:left to the checkbox and switch the messsage with the textbox

```
 <label  for='agreement'> I accept the TOS</label>
    <input id="agreement" name="agreement" type="checkbox" style = 'float:left' />

        <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
```

Comment: This resolves the positioning issue but unfortunately i'd still need to figure out how to set the position for 1 of the fields